# linux semaphore using in IPC Behavior inconsistency,the code result(on the image below) sometimes is out of my expectation,I don't kown why

Tags: c++, linux, semaphore

I am tring to learn the linux semaphore,I found an example on one blog,so I try to run it,but the result sometimes is right.sometime is wrong,I don't kown why.I think it should be run well.thanks for your help.the result can be seen on the below picture.it's really wired when I try to printf the address of the semaphore,the result become right,but when I comment the printf line,it can be wrong.I print the semaphore in parent process and child process,the address are same.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd, i, count = 0, nloop = 10, zero = 0, *ptr;
    sem_t mutex;
    //open a file and map it into memory
    fd = open("log.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
    write(fd, &zero, sizeof(int));
    ptr = (int *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
    /* create, initialize semaphore */
    if (sem_init(&mutex, 1, 1) < 0) //
    {
        perror("semaphore initilization");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (fork() == 0) { /* child process*/

        // printf("child's sem %p\n",&mutex); //when I uncomment this line 
        for (i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
            sem_wait(&mutex);
            printf("child: %d\n", ++(*ptr));
            // fflush(stdout);
            sem_post(&mutex);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    /* back to parent process */
    // printf("parent's sem %p\n",&mutex); //when I uncomment this line 
    for (i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        printf("parent: %d\n", ++(*ptr));
        // fflush(stdout);
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    printf("parent exit\n");
    
    exit(0);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what result is classified as right and what results are classified as wrong.

Comment: yeah,you can find the image in the link below the question.thanks

Comment: the first runing result is right,the second one is not expected

Comment: you can runing the code on your machine,I think you will get the unexpected result if your try several times

Comment: You can't have free running semaphore in a for loop. You will have zero control over what runs next. The scheduler decides what will run next. You need to use conditional variables or flags with if statements to control the flow of the program.

Comment: The parent process can complete and exit before the child leaving a dangling process. You need to `wait()` on the child. See `[man 2 wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) including the example at the end. You may also enjoy [pthread Tutorial - Peter Chapin](http://lemuria.cis.vtc.edu/~pchapin/TutorialPthread/pthread-Tutorial.pdf)  which I found quite helpful.

Comment: but if I put the for_loop in a thread, it's works well all the time@DarkSorrow

Comment: @Liu Yuqing, Even if you put for loop in a thread, synchronization is not guaranteed. You have to manually apply synchronization logic. What might be happening is that as both threads running in same process the probability that you get the pattern you desire is much higher than with 2 separate process when OS schedular is controlling everything.

Comment: thanks .I used the wait() before parent process exit,but the result sometimes still confusing.@DavidC.Rankin  `parent: 1
parent: 2
parent: 3
parent: 4
parent: 5
parent: 6
parent: 7
parent: 8
parent: 9
parent: 10
child: 8
child: 9
child: 10
child: 11
child: 12
child: 13
child: 14
child: 15
child: 16
child: 17
parent exit`

Comment: Parent and child reference different semaphores, one a fork()d copy of the other.  In order for sem_init() to properly initialize a _pshared_ semaphore, _the semaphore itself must reside in shared memory_ (as, e.g., by another MAP_SHARED mmap()).

Comment: sem_init man page says "(Since a child created by fork(2) inherits its  par‐
       ent's memory mappings, it can also access the semaphore.)",and I print the sem address in the two process,it was same. @pilcrow

Comment: thanks.it's a little bit out of my kownledge, I think the semaphore already do the synchronization.@DarkSorrow

Comment: the result of printf could be unreliable. Have you tried to read the log.txt at the end ?

Comment: sorry, I have no log.txt,I just output the value to the terminal@nhatnq

Comment: The results are not surprising at all. The problem is you only put `ptr` in shared memory. Since you `fork()` your `semaphore` must be located in shared-memory. The semaphore should be in the `mmap`ed memory as well. See [man 3 sem_init PP4](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) I'm not export on pthreads, but I suspect between the `wait()`and `mutex` not being in shared memory causes the semaphore count mismatch since after `fork()` the semaphore `mutex` in the child no longer synchronized with the parent.

Comment: man 3 sem_init says (Since a child created by fork(2) inherits its parent's memory mappings, it can also access the semaphore.) and I print the address of the semaphore int two processes,it was same. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq6Qo.png) @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Access and update across processes are two separate things. While the parent and child will both have access to a `sem_t` named `mutex`, after `fork()` they are no longer the same.  If you are not using shared memory for `mutex` that is where the semaphore count (increment/decrement) becomes unsynchronized.